# How to use split strings with closed brackets as the separator

Tags: python, list, split

If I have a messy string like `'[Carrots] [Broccoli] (cucumber)-(tomato) irrelevant [spinach]'` and I want to split it into a list so that each part within any bracket is an item like `['Carrots', 'Broccoli', 'cucumber', 'tomato', 'spinach']` How would I do this? I can't figure out a way to make the `.split()` method work.

Comment: Look into `re.split`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex

```
import re

s = '[Carrots] [Broccoli] (cucumber)-(tomato) irrelevant [spinach]'

lst = [x[0] or x[1] for x in re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]|\((.*?)\)', s)]
print(lst)
```

**Output**

```
['Carrots', 'Broccoli', 'cucumber', 'tomato', 'spinach']
```

**Explanation**

Regex pattern to match

```
r'\[(.*?)\]|\((.*?)\)'
```

Subpattern 1: To match items in square brackets i.e. [...]

```
\[(.*?)\]  # Use \[ and \] since  [, ] are special characters
           #  we have to escape so they will be literal
 (.*?)     # Is a Lazy match of all characters
```

Subpattern 2: To match in parentheses i.e. (..)

```
\((.*?)\)   # Use \( and \) since  (, ) are special characters
            # we have to escape so they will be literal
```

Since we are looking for either of the two patterns we use:

```
'|'         # which is or between the two subpatterns
            # to match Subpattern1 or Subpattern
```

The expression

```
re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]|\((.*?)\)', s)

[('Carrots', ''), ('Broccoli', ''), ('', 'cucumber'), ('', 'tomato'), ('spinach', '')]
```

The result is in the first or second tuple.  So we use:

```
[x[0] or x[1] for x in re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]|\((.*?)\)', s)]
```

To extract the data from the first or second tuple and place it into a list.

Answer (score 0):

Without any error handling whatsoever (like checking for nested or unbalanced brackets):

```py
def parse(expr):
    opening = "(["
    closing = ")]"
    result = []
    current_item = ""
    for char in expr:
        if char in opening:
            current_item = ""
            continue
        if char in closing:
            result.append(current_item)
            continue
        current_item += char
    return result

print(parse("(a)(b) stuff (c) [d] more stuff - (xxx)."))

>>> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'xxx']
```

Depending on your needs, this might already be good enough...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no other brackets or operators (e.g. '-') than the ones present in your example string are used, try

```py
s = '[Carrots] [Broccoli] (cucumber)-(tomato) irrelevant [spinach]'

words = []
for elem in s.replace('-', ' ').split():
    if '[' in elem or '(' in elem:
        words.append(elem.strip('[]()'))
```

Or with [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```py
words = [elem.strip('[]()') for elem in s.replace('-', ' ').split() if '[' in elem or '(' in elem]
```